# How to avoid Kafka latency spikes caused by log segment flush

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, latency

We're experiencing a big latency spikes (two orders of magnitude) on 99th percentile in our Kafka deployment. We googled a bit and found that this is pretty well documented phenomenon: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9693

In the ticket, suggested "solution" is disabling log flush but that's hardly an acceptable solution if you care about data consistency.

We've tried to tune around log sizes, flush intervals etc. but that's only delaying the log flush doing nothing to the magnitude of the spike.

**Question**

Is there any real solution/workaround to this problem? To be clear, I'm talking about how to lower the spike down to the minimum.